# How do I install Opera?

Tags: 11.10, opera

I have installed ubuntu 11.10 Beta version.
now I wanted to install opera and I downloaded the .deb package, but it wont work.

I also tried the package to open it with Ubuntu Software Center but the USC crashed.

tell me how to proceed?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if you still need it but I found a solution to install opera in Ubuntu 11.10 (not beta version) using apt-get at `liberiangeek.net` by some guy named Richard(I think).

#### Here is is:

To get started,  press Ctrl – Alt – T  on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the commands below to add Opera’s public key.

> sudo sh -c 'wget -O - http://deb.opera.com/archive.key | apt-key add -'

After adding the key, run the command below to add Opera repository

> sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera.list

Next, copy the past the line below into the file and save it.

> deb http://deb.opera.com/opera/ stable non-free

After that run the commands below to update your system.

> sudo apt-get update

Finally, run the commands below to install Opera

> sudo apt-get install opera

Enjoy

You can access the tutorial by [this link](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2011/12/install-opera-web-browser-using-apt-get-in-ubuntu-11-10-oneiric-ocelot/) also.

Answer (score 3):

You should download gdebi from the software centre or use`sudo apt-get install gdebi` and open the .deb file with gdebi

Answer (score 2):

Open a terminal and navigate to the location where you saved the DEB file. Run the following command, replacing `[pkg]` with the filename of the DEB package you downloaded:

> `sudo dpkg -i [pkg]`

Comment: When i tried to open it with terminal, this message showed.

dpkg: error: dpkg status database is locked by another process

Comment: @AaSs: This means that another program is currently installing / removing packages - only one program can work with packages at a time.

Comment: OK...I tried it on cold start, but still receiving the error.
Someone told me that it is the fault of broken dependency.
How to fix that?

Comment: Broken Dependancies can be fixed by running sudo apt-get install -f

Answer (score -1):

Here is why wont install and the fix...

http://my.opera.com/community/forums/topic.dml?id=1124872&t=1319006959&page=1#comment10571122

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Imagine the linked site goes down for maintenance or forever - your answer would become worthless.